# Sparse Bayesian Learning Algorithm in Python - MSE vs. SNR

Tags: python, optimization, sparsity, bayesian-estimation

I am implementing SBL in python. I have plotted a graph between MSE (mean squared error) and SNR (Signal to Noise ratio)
The graph must be decreasing, but mine is decreasing till the SNR is negative. As soon as it is positive, the graph shoots up.
I have checked the code many times, and even the scale of snr and mse.
I still can't find the mistake.

**Is this increase possible or have I done blunder anywhere?**

[image: My result is]

Comment: So if you have no noise at all, your MSE is infinite? Does this make sense?

Comment: We need more information about the model and approach to solve.